# Read pdf file from sd-card with the help of webview

Tags: android

Is it possible to read pdf file stored in my sd card to view in web view.
I tried using

```
            WebView webview = new WebView(myactivity.this);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/pdf" + "/ypc.pdf");

            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            webview.loadUrl(uri.toString());
```

but got no results,. is any other way possible

Answer (score 0):

I think PDF reader is not in-built with Android-WebView or any web-browser. it is a plugin to web-browser like Adobe PDF Reader with our PC browsers (Mozilla, Chrome, Opera, etc.)

So you must configure external PDF Reader app with Android-WebView, to read PDF files with webview.

Otherwise try Google Docs Viewer to read PDF file, but you must have internet connection and set appropriate permissions to your app.

Replace last line of your code with below line.

```
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + uri.toString());
```

I hope it may help you.